# How to create a function setInterval with clearInterval inside it?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a app that must send the user to homepage after some events. For this I use this bit of code that works good:

```
var waitime = 1000;
var handle=setInterval(function () {  
        $('.wrapper').html(divResp);
        $('body').append(js);
        clearInterval(handle);   
    }, waitime);
```

But I was trying to create a function to be called instead copy the code every time. So, after some reseach [setInterval and how to use clearInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/setinterval-and-how-to-use-clearinterval) and [clearInterval outside of method containing setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253938/clearinterval-outside-of-method-containing-setinterval) I have create this one:

```
function refreshToHomePage3(handle,waitime){
     return setInterval(function () {  
                    $('.wrapper').html(divResp);
                    $('body').append(js);
                    clearInterval(handle);   
                  }, waitime);
}
```

The problem is when a call the function, like this:

```
var refreshIntervalId=refreshToHomePage3(refreshIntervalId,waitime);
```

I have a infinite loop. I already solved the problem using setTimeout instead of setInterval and the function became like this one:

```
function refreshToHomePage2(waitime){
     setTimeout(function () {  
           $('.wrapper').html(divResposta);
           $('body').append(js); 
     }, waitime);
}
```

But I was wondering how to solve the problem using setInterval and clearInterval. Any thougths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is prefered here. But you can use `setInterval` like this..

```
function refreshToHomePage3(handle,waitime){
     handle = setInterval(function () {  
                    $('.wrapper').html(divResp);
                    $('body').append(js);
                    clearInterval(handle);   
                  }, waitime);
     return handle;
}
```

---

Actually there is no need to pass a handle variable into the function.

```js
function refreshToHomePage3(waitime){
     var handle = setInterval(function () {  
                    alert("called after waitime");
                    clearInterval(handle);   
                  }, waitime);
     return handle;
}   

var handle = refreshToHomePage3(5000);
```

Comment: That's what OP does in `refreshToHomePage3`

Comment: I don't think so. In his example he is not setting the handle variable. @AmitJoki

Comment: First I guessed. But then changed. I cannot say that... Apologies.. @AmitJoki

Comment: You're just assigning what is returned by setInterval to a variable  and then returning it. What OP did was also the same but without the use of variable

Comment: That's not the thing I changed. The OP use `clearInterval(handle)` without assigning handle to anything. It doesn't clear the interval. I set the `handle` to `clearInterval reference` first so that `clearInterval(handle)` works..

Comment: Hi Sampath. After see Your code I realize that you dont need to return nothing and you dont need to initialize a variable affecting a funtion. Just call the function name and that is all. It works

Answer (score 0):

You're clearing the interval after the first time the code runs. So what you're doing is just what `setTimeout` does. You need `setTimeout` which runs only once after the waiting for `waitTime`.

```
function refreshToHomePage(handle, waitime) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.wrapper').html(divResp);
        $('body').append(js);
        clearInterval(handle);
    }, waitime);
}
```

Comment: You are not assigning setTimeout to handle. How can you clearInterval?

Comment: Yep. Then why is it inside the function? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be executed just once after the wait time, `setInterval` is not the right function for this job, but `setTimeout` is.

`setInterval` will execute your code every *n* seconds until you execute `clearInterval`. However, `setTimeout` will execute your code **once** after *n* seconds and is therefore the correct approach for your problem.

Don't try to make setInterval something that it isn't :)